# How to display data from SQLite Database into RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-recyclerview

I want to display data from my SQLite Database to my RecyclerView (with LinearLayoutManager). I created the RecyclerView layout for the list and a CardView layout for the single item. I created the database with Recipe table and I can save a new Recipe. My goal is to show the title of Recipe inside the CardView.

**Recipe class**

```
public class Recipe {

private int id;
private String title;
private String photo;
private String instructions;
private int targetPeople;
private int time;



public Recipe() {

    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.photo = photo;
    this.instructions = instructions;
    this.targetPeople = targetPeople;
    this.time = time;
}
```

(plus setter/getter method)

Inside the DatabaseHelper, I created a method to get all the Recipes adding to a List:

```
public List<Recipe> getAllRecipes() {

    // sorting orders
    String sortOrder =
            RECIPE_TITLE + " ASC";
    List<Recipe> recipeList = new ArrayList<Recipe>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TBL_RECIPE, null);

    // Traversing through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        do {

            Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
            recipe.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TITLE")));

            // Adding user record to list
            recipeList.add(recipe);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // return user list
    return recipeList;
}
```

This is my Adapter class with ViewHolder class for the RecyclerView:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Recipe> recipeList;

//constructor of adapter
public MyAdapter(Context mContext, List<Recipe> recipeList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.recipeList = recipeList;

}

//ViewHolder Class
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public final TextView textViewTitle;

    //constructor for ViewHolder
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionView);
    }

}

//return an instance of ViewHolder Class
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int position) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item_card, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

//binding data to our ViewHolder
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    // retrieve UI elements inside viewHolder object

    viewHolder.textViewTitle.setText(recipeList.get(position).getTitle());

}

//return the size of the list
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return recipeList.size();
}
}
```

Finally, I declared RecyclerView, List, Adapter, etc in the MainActivity,
where I created a method to display all Recipes:

```
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private void displayAllRecipes() {
    // AsyncTask is used that SQLite operation does not block the UI Thread.
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Recipe>>() {
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Recipe> doInBackground(Void... params) {

            recipeList.clear();
            recipeList.addAll(dbHelper. getAllRecipes());
            return recipeList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Recipe> aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            resultAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

There's no errors but it doesn't work.

Comment: wehre you are setting layout manager?

Comment: you checked that your database have data? put `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);`  just below your this line `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TBL_RECIPE, null);` and see in logcat you getting data or not

Comment: @NoumanCh inside the XML layout file

Comment: @AshwiniViolet database has data. At first I tried to display the title in a simple ListView and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you have passed the arrayList into adapter and set adapter to recyclerView.

Comment: I made it. I think the error is inside this line: recipe.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TITLE")));

Comment: may be your column name is not correct..make sure you have same column name as you defined while creating database.

Comment: remove your code from asyncTask and then run..put your code inside onCreate Method.

Comment: just for testing purpose..add some entries into your database first..as it won't be crash in onCreate!

Comment: I solved. Simply, in the new object instantiated to save the new Recipe in the database, I didn't pass the arguments. 
So I declared this --> Recipe recipe = new Recipe() 
instead of this ---> Recipe recipe = new Recipe(title, photo, instructions, target, timep);
Thanks for helping

Comment: I think I understand how this works here. You populate a list with data from a database an this list is used to fill the `RecyclerView`. Call me pedantic, but this is not really elegant, is it? I mean, I don't know another way and this is surely working, but isn't there a way to more or less directly bind the database to the view? Like we had with `CursorAdapter` and `ListView` in the good old days? 